x-field-extra-annotation not working on $ref field
Using
                <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>6.6.0</version>

and following example yaml:
    TestObj:
      type: object
      properties:
        field1:
          x-field-extra-annotation: "@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore"
          type: string
        field2:
          x-field-extra-annotation: "@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore"
          type: array
          items:
            $ref: "#/components/schemas/Foo"
        field3:
          x-field-extra-annotation: "@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore"
          $ref: "#/components/schemas/Foo"
    Foo:
      type: object
      properties:
        field1:
          type: string

Generated class is the following:
    @jakarta.annotation.Generated(value = "org.openapitools.codegen.languages.JavaJAXRSSpecServerCodegen")
    public class TestObj  implements Serializable {
        @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore
        private @Valid String field1;
        @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore
        private @Valid List<Foo> field2;
        private @Valid Foo field3;
    }

How can I force the openapi plugin to include the @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore annotation on field3 without insert the annotation on Foo object yaml definition?
